# How do I set location of button to be top right of screen?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to set the location of a specific button to be the top right of the current window. is this possible in c# [WINDOWS FORM APPLICATION]?

Comment: You need to specify which framework you are using for your UI (Winforms, WPF, or ASP.NET if its a web project).

Comment: sorry, just done it!

Comment: no, but you can put it in a TableLayoutPanel control

Comment: TLP will neither be needed nor even helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, normally one would use the UI designer for that. I'm assuming you mean "How do I get it to stay there even if the window is resized". If that is the case, than simply use the `Anchor` option in the properties pane.

[image: Screenshot of VS properties pane]

Comment: This does not work

Comment: Just to make it clear: Deviating from the screenshot, you set the value to `Top, Right`, didn't you...?

Comment: Those are the default settings. You need to set the anchor options to Top, Right

Comment: @khlr it was already set to top right...

Comment: __Plus__, of course, __place__ it to the right!! Then it'll stay there.

Comment: @TaW if I increase the screen size, the button will not move

Comment: You mean the Form.Size, right? Yes it __will__ stick to the same distance from the right egde of its __Parent__. Is it sitting on the Form or some other control?